# javascript array - how to not allow equal values inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays

The code:

```js
let ace = [1, 2, 3, 4];

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  console.log(ace[i]); // elements
}
```

how can i make a if else inside this for to not allow same values on the array?

[EDIT]
can i make this way somehow?

```
ace = [1,1,2,3];

    ace.forEach(dejavu);

    function dejavu(item, index) {
      var card = item;
      console.log(card);
    }
```

Comment: use a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) generated from the array:

```js
let ace = [1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3];

for (let el of new Set(ace)) {
    console.log(el); // will log 1 2 3 4
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create new array without duplications:

```
const noDuplications = [...new Set(ace)]
```

Comment: i'm trying to make a condition to a game board.

Comment: something like:

Answer (score 0):

I wanna not allow lines and columns equal values. Manage to do it with if for checking equal values on row with:

````js
    if (
      ace[0] == ace[1] ||
      ace[0] == ace[2] ||
      ace[0] == ace[3] ||
      ace[1] == ace[2] ||
      ace[1] == ace[3] ||
      ace[2] == ace[3]
    ) {
      console.log("not yet winner");
    }
``` But this is ugly, and not very useful
````